# Angular nested template driven forms

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I'm trying to use nested template driven forms, but the ngModel in my `PostEditorComponent` textarea can't find the `ngForm` located in `ModalFormComponent`. This is my current setup:

```
Component({
    selector: 'modal-form',
    template: `
        <div class="modal-window">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form #form="ngForm">
                    <ng-content></ng-content>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    `
})
export class ModalFormComponent {
}

@Component({
    selector: 'post-editor',
    template: `
        <textarea [(ngModel)]="postContent" required name="postContent"></textarea>
    `
})
export class PostEditorComponent {
    public postContent: string;
}

@Component({
    selector: 'write-post',
    template: `
        <modal-form>
            <label>
                Post type: <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="postTitle" name="postTitle"/>
            </label>
            <post-editor></post-editor>
        </modal-form>
    `
})
export class WritePostComponent {
    public postTitle: string;
}
```

If I try using `viewProviders: [{provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: NgForm}]` in `PostEditorComponent` Angular throws an `NullInjectorError: No provider for NgForm!`

Manual linking using `@ViewChildren(NgModel)` and `ngForm.addControl(model)` could be a solution, but is error prone as I would have to manage references, handle `AfterViewInit`, `OnDestroy`, etc.

Any ideas on how to inject the form instance into `PostEditorComponent` view?